# Difference between 'google-chrome-stable' and 'google-chrome' binaries

Tags: google-chrome, binary

There are two binaries in my `/usr/bin` directory, `google-chrome` and `google-chrome-stable`. I wonder if both belongs to the same package.

```
$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep google
google-chrome
google-chrome-stable
```

Which one to use BTW?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case it's all the same. `google-chrome` starts the 
configured version, see at the end of my answer.

First let's start a little test:

```
% ls -laog /usr/bin/google-chrome       
lrwxrwxrwx 1 31 Mär 17  2015 /usr/bin/google-chrome -> /etc/alternatives/google-chrome

% ls -laog /etc/alternatives/google-chrome
lrwxrwxrwx 1 27 Mär 17  2015 /etc/alternatives/google-chrome -> /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

As you can see

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

is a symbolic link to

```
/etc/alternatives/google-chrome
```

and

```
/etc/alternatives/google-chrome
```

is a symbolic link to

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

---

If you have installed e.g. `google-chrome-beta` and `google-chrome-stable`, you can start

```
sudo update-alternatives --config google-chrome
```

to change the behavior, eg. in my case

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative google-chrome (providing /usr/bin/google-chrome).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/google-chrome-beta     150       manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Answer (score -1):

Google-Chrome-Stable version will be tested out and bugs will fix before the public release

More information available in below link

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/zdycfubS1zg